# C:\Windows.old has a phantom permission, how do I rid myself of it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, ntfs

I just used Clean Install to reinstall on Windows 10 1809 (big mistake, I know). It's the official refreshed version, but it grants `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` permission to `C:\Windows.old`.

This is relevant because inheritance is sticking to all of the files, even in server mode. Any attempt to remove it looks as though it succeeds, but nothing happens.

These are all of my personal files and documents, appdata, etc, going back many years, so the relevant portion is about 200GB, so copying (which resets the modified date anyway) isn't really feasible.

I need to either

- move the files and break the inheritance chain; tried this using old PowerShell trick (move file, reset inheritance via `SetAccessRuleProtection`; the phantom permission sticks from "Parent Object" which this normally negates),
- remove the phantom permission before moving files.

I've already taken ownership of the folder, that's not helping any. To be clear, I want to **remove** the `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` permission from `C:\Windows.old` so my files aren't tainted with a bad security permission.

Screenshot of `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES`, removing it "succeeds", but it's still there:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87011/discussion-between-thegoddessinari-and-ramhound).

Comment: This is usually a driver package. Removing the driver clears the lock. This question has been asked and answered here before. Did you check the other questions about windows.old?

Comment: I checked other questions, there isn't a driver involved that I'm aware unless Microsoft is being stupid with one. Things aren't locked, there is no permission denied, removing "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" iterates through all of the files like usual, no errors, but the phantom permission stays. Same with cacls, icacls, powershell set-acl, etc.

Comment: Another point: A "clean reinstall" typically involves formatting your hard drive prior to or during the installation process. If "Windows.old" still exists, that means you did not run a "clean reinstall". Could you clarify the precise method and steps you used to update your computer to build 1809?

Comment: And finally, what are you actually trying to accomplish: Are you just trying to remove the All Application Packages permission entry from your own files (what the body of the question seems to say) or are you trying to delete Windows.old and you believe this permission is preventing you from doing so, or something else entirely? Please EDIT your question to make this more clear.

Comment: The question was clear that I wanted to recover the files, **not** delete them, and I wanted to remove the `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` permission, which it's not doing no matter how many times it's removed. And "clean reinstall" seems to mean using Clean Install, and producing a Windows.old in the first place, otherwise I'd have mentioned formatting, and there wouldn't be a Windows.old. The screenshot is after removing the permission and reopening the folder properties.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the files in Windows.old? You should move them elsewhere and then remove the permissions.

Comment: You can't remove the permission, and moving them elsewhere **carries the permission with it**, as it says in the original post. Thank you for the pointlessly unhelpful and extremely pedantic suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the below steps for deleting the Windows.Old folder by login as administrator.

1. Press the Windows + R keys to open the Run dialog, type **cleanmgr**,
   and click/tap on OK to open Disk Cleanup.
2. If you have more than one drive or partition on your PC, then select the Windows C: drive, and click/tap on OK.
3. Click/tap on the **Cleanup system files** button.
4. If prompted by UAC, click/tap on Yes.
5. Repeat step 2 above.
6. Check the **Previous Windows installation(s)** box, and click/tap on OK.
7. Click/tap on **Delete Files** to confirm.
8. When Disk Cleanup finishes, the C:\Windows.old folder will be deleted.

**Update:** If you want to move the files from the Windows.Old folder, you may need to take ownership and grant full permissions to your account. This can be done by using the freeware [TakeOwnershipPro](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2650).

Comment: I really obviously don't want to delete all of my personal files and documents, nor would that at-all help with the issue.

Comment: @TheGoddessInari I've updated my answer. To solve the permission issue, you need to change the ownership of all files inside C:\Windows.old.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It's not about permission denied, or any other error, but a bad phantom permission that persists regardless of trying to remove it.